# Integrate Bing Maps in an Access application

Tags: ms-access, vba, bing-maps

I have the following requirement and looking for advice for the best method for implementing bing maps in an Access 2013 application.

1. Enter an address into a field and have bing maps geocode and return the lat longs.
2. Apply the lat longs and display a push pin to a bing map embedded in an Access form.
3. The bing map needs to have controls available (panning, zooming etc...).

I've played around with using the REST services but as far as I can tell you can only use static maps.  I've also used various urls (www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx) but you don't get as much control of the display of the map.

I'm just looking for ideas and suggestions for best practices.

Comment: You need to add a bit more about what you tried, and what type of app you are building (Sharepoint hosted web app or classic Access desktop app?). One way to implement maps in an application is to use the browser control. You will still be limited in what to how you can control the actions in the browser, but you can provide some of the functionality by changing the URL's parameters.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Access 2013 you could use the Bing Maps Access Web App: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/store/bing-maps-for-access-WA104324286.aspx?queryid=4586595d%2D09d8%2D492f%2D9a04%2D9ed2ebefb0b5&css=maps&CTT=1

If you are using older versions of office you can create your own solution using either the Bing Maps WPF or V7 JavaScript control. The JavaScript control is the most widely used control and I would recommend using that one. You can find lots of documentation on it here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx

Also, here is a useful interactive SDK: http://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7#CreateMap1

Also, to use Bing Maps you will need to create a Bing Maps account and key. I recommend creating a basic, not a trial key, for development and testing as trial keys expire after 90 days while basic one's done. You can find some information on creating keys here: http://www.microsoft.com/maps/create-a-bing-maps-key.aspx

Comment: Does `Bing Maps for Access` work for desktop apps too? Or is it only web?

Comment: with your comments below, is part of your answer that this is not legally possible? What is the difference between what you are saying here and pointing to the Bing site from the WebBrowser control? Is there another way to get web content into Access other than the WebBrowser control (or the IE control)?

Comment: What I'm saying is using the Bing Maps API or premade solutions for Access. The Access Web App has a license for Bing Maps usage internally unlike the embedded maps and consumer site.

Comment: How you you propose to do this for non web apps then?

Comment: Well, the Office Web App, actually works in the desktop version of office as well. If you use the Bing Maps API's you can either use the Bing Maps WPF control with works in both WPF and WinForm applications, or you can use a WebBrowser control and host a local web page in it with the JavaScript map control.

Answer (score 1):

This is going to answer part 2 and 3 of your question. I didn't look for how to get lat/long from an address.

Access forms have the web browser control.

You can build up a URL and set the control source of the browser control. See [this MS page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn217138.aspx) for what parameters can be used to build up the URL you want.

For example this, I dropped a textbox and awebbrowser control onto a form. I called the textbox `text1` and set the control source for the web browser control to `=([text1])`. When the form loaded I pasted in this URL

```
http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?cp=47.677797~-122.122013&lvl=10
```

It rendered as this

[image: bing map in an Access form with URL bar as a textbox]

You could build up your URL, according to how MS wants you to build it up, and how you need to and set it to the "URL bar" textbox.

Comment: Linking to the Bing Maps consumer site from an internal app like this is against the terms of use of Bing Maps.

Comment: @rbrundritt Is it? I see [this](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/assets/docs/terms.aspx) which states "You may not use the Embedded Maps Service for internal business applications." in the "Bing Maps Embedded Maps Service Terms of Use" section which explicitly says "The following Bing Maps Embedded Maps Service Terms of Use (“Terms”) apply to Your use of the Bing Maps Embedded Maps Service only." And at the top it distinguished between "Microsoft Bing Maps and MapPoint Web Service" and "Embedded Maps Service".

Comment: @rbrundritt I mean I'm no expert here at all. And you look like you've used Bing maps a lot more than I have so if you say so I'll put a caveat on the answer.